# Figuring out (paralax?) scrolling effect

Tags: javascript, css

Does anyone know how [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20111118073106/http://tedxportland.com/) effect was achieved? I can't quite figure out if it's an video that basically plays as one scrolls or an image or what.

Comment: That was a horrible effect, please don't use :) On another note, you have the source right there. Just look.

Comment: I wouldn't be asking if I was able to figure it out. I thought someone more familiar with web would be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
parallax();
});
function parallax(){
var scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
$('.bg').css('top',-(scrolled*0.1)+'px');
$('.bg2').css('top',-(scrolled*0.2)+'px');
}
```

This function invokes a parallax effect

And this adds the corresponding css changes, its very similar to the example you have shown, bit simpler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(window).scroll(function() { 
if ($(this).scrollTop()> 500 ) {
$(".bg2").css({
'-webkit-transform' : 'rotateX(' + "180deg" + ')',
'-moz-transform'    :  'rotateX(' + "180deg" + ')',
'-ms-transform'     : 'rotateX(' + "180deg" + ')',
'-o-transform'      :  'rotateX(' + "180deg" + ')',
'transform'         :  'rotateX(' + "180deg" + ')'});
$(".bg").css({
'-webkit-transform' : 'rotateY(' + "180deg" + ')',
'-moz-transform'    :  'rotateY(' + "180deg" + ')',
'-ms-transform'     : 'rotateY(' + "180deg" + ')',
'-o-transform'      :  'rotateY(' + "180deg" + ')',
'transform'         :  'rotateY(' + "180deg" + ')' + 'scale(' + "0.5,0.33" +   ')'     +      'translateY('     + "-1250px" + ')'
});

}

});
});
```

Link to the codepen page:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/yYKyaN

Comment: @chrae

Keep in mind i have given a css transition time to the backgrounds, that way the scroll and parallax effect carries on for a bit after you stop scrolling. You can remove that and it sill works.